# При преобразовании svg в png <text> искажает цвет

Tags: php, svg, imagick

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 123.73 36.69">
  <defs>
    <style type="text/css">
    <![CDATA[ 
    text.cls-2 { 
      opacity:0.5; 
      font-size:20px; 
      fill:#d0d0d0; 
      font-family:Roboto-Medium, Roboto; 
      font-weight:500; 
      letter-spacing:0.01em; 
    } 
    ]]>
    </style>
  </defs>
  <g>
    <text class="cls-2" transform="translate(29.68 17.11)">ID 123456</text>
  </g>
</svg>
```

```php
$usmap = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/path/img.svg';

$im = new Imagick();
$im->setBackgroundColor(new ImagickPixel('transparent'));
$svg = file_get_contents($usmap);
$im->readImageBlob('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>' . $svg);

$im->setImageFormat("png24");

$im->writeImage($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/path/watermark.png');
$im->clear();
$im->destroy();
```

Результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Хотя цвет должен быть бежевым.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не указал реальные размеры svg

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 150 50" width="1920" height="581">
<defs>
    <style type="text/css">
        <![CDATA[
                    text.cls-2 {
                        opacity:0.9;
                        font-size:20px;
                        fill:#d0d0d0;
                        font-family:Roboto-Medium, Roboto;
                        font-weight:500;
                        letter-spacing:0.01em;
                    }
                ]]>
    </style>
</defs>
<g>
    <text class="cls-2" text-anchor="end" x="83%" y="15">ID 123456</text>
</g>
</svg>
```

```php
$usmap = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/path/img.svg';

$im = new Imagick();
$im->setBackgroundColor(new ImagickPixel('transparent'));
$svg = file_get_contents($usmap);
$im->readImageBlob('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>' . $svg);

$im->setImageFormat("png24");

$im->writeImage($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/path/watermark.png');
$im->clear();
$im->destroy();
```

Результат
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]